# Computed property “eleron” was assigned to but it has no setter

Tags: vue.js

How to fix it?

```
computed: {
  ...mapGetters({
    eleron: 'promoter/eleron',
  }),
},
```

GetInfo (call when press search button):

```
getInfo() {
    this.loading = true;
    axios.post('/srt', {
      search: this.search
    })
    .then((response) => {this.eleron = response.data, console.log(response.data), this.loading = false;});
},
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are mapping the getters from `vuex`. This means that you can only get the value from the store, you cannot write to it.

You need to also map a [mutation](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/mutations.html#committing-mutations-in-components).

Something like this should work, depending on the fact that you have a mutation defined on the store:

```
methods: {
 ...mapMutations([
  'updateEleron'
 ]),
}
```

And then call it in the promise callback

```
this.updateEleron(response.data)
```

Note: vuex offers read only access to variables from outside the store. Writing to a variable needs to be done from inside a `mutation` or `action`.

Comment: Thanks for answers, new error... : ReferenceError: mapMutations is not defined

Comment: Did you follow the link regarding mapping mutations? You most likely didn't include it. Use import { mapMutations } from 'vuex'

Comment: Am vazut ca esti roman, e ok. Am importat totul ok, dar urm. eroare " unknown mutation type: updateEleron", crezi ca imi poti da un Discord sau ceva unde sa voribm in asamblu? Pot plati pentru ajutorul pe care mi-l oferi, sunt inca un incepator in Vue (nu si in programare in special), as avea nevoie de cineva... Multumesc!

Comment: Try radu.dita#7357 on discord.